# Why can't I map `ApplicationUser` to a view model with AutoMapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, automapper

My `ApplicationUser` is fairly standard as generated by the MVC 5 project template, with the addition of `FullName` and the `IPayCaddyEntity` interface:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IPayCaddyEntity
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

The new interface is only:

```
public interface IPayCaddyEntity
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and is already implemented by `IdentityUser` having a `string` `Id` property. Everything builds and mostly runs OK. Then I want to map a list of users to a viewmodel:

```
public class PlayerViewModel: PayCaddyViewModel
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

They should map nicely, both have the same type `FullName` property. I try this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, PlayerViewModel>().ReverseMap();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

then this:

```
var players = _db.Users.ToList()
var model = Mapper.Map<IList<PlayerViewModel>>(players);
```

The `Map` call throws an exception.

I am trying to include the Identity entities in my own database, and the `Users` property is a `DbSet<ApplicationUser` that my DbContext inherits from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`.

The full stack trace is:

```
[AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
ApplicationUser -> PlayerViewModel
PayCaddy.Data.Models.ApplicationUser -> PayCaddy.Client.Models.PlayerViewModel

Destination path:
IList`1[0]

Source value:
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_4342C7C6E2802320D156341C80F8DED74454F28D43628C766C6951DB971B9BDA]
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) +610
   AutoMapper.Mappers.EnumerableMapperBase`1.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +482
   AutoMapper.Mappers.CollectionMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper) +126
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) +610
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.MapCore(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, MappingOperationOptions options) +179
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, Action`1 opts) +59
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Action`1 opts) +92
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source) +93
   AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Object source) +62
   PayCaddy.Client.Controllers.<PlayersIndex>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\Development\Cordova\PayCaddy\PayCaddy.Client\Controllers\AccountController.cs:65
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9723757
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Are you sure the CreateMap gets called? Where do you call it?

Comment: @thepirat000 In the controller constructor. I know it's not the ideal place, but I wanted to see it being called close to where `Map` is called. I first had it in the static constructor of the view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem must be the `CreateMap` not being called, since your code works fine as you can see in [this .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NJD0RZ).

Double check if the `CreateMap` is being called properly. Try calling it in Application_Start() method, Global.asax.cs file.

Comment: Great, thanks. It shall remain a mystery why the `CreateMap` in the controller ctor wasn't working, but `Application_Start()` is fine.